# Log cron process output to both stdout and log file?

Tags: bash, cron, io-redirection, tee

I have a script running every minute on cron and want to output the script output to terminal as well as to a log file. I think I use `tee -a` for this.

Right now the python script just prints the current time.

`* * * * * python script.py | tee -a script_times.log`

The above logs to the file but not to stdout.

I thought `tee` outputs to stdout *and* to any given file.

How can I make it log out as well as log to file?

Comment: `tee` does send output to stdout as well as a file, but in a cron job, stdout is not a terminal. cron jobs run completely detached & independent from any interactive session you may happen to have running.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to write output to a specific terminal, you'd need to redirect it there, for example, `* * * * * python script.py | tee -a script_times.log > /dev/pts/0`. Replace `/dev/pts/0` with your terminal's device file, typically found using the `tty` command

Comment: Note that "your terminal's device file" is fundamentally transient. You'll tend to get the same one over and over because the allocation algorithm is so simple (it just uses the first one that's available), but it's not really "your terminal" in any permanent sense.